# How to update table from another table or excel file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table T1(col1, col2, info), col1 is primary key. Now I have a another table T2 (col1, col2, col3), col1 is primary key. For example,

T1:

```
col1 col2 info
num1 data1 info1
num2 data2 info2
```

T2

```
col1 col2 col3
num1 data1 Y
num2 data2 N
num3 data3 NULL
```

How do I write a script to update T1 with T2? The result should be
T1:

```
col1 col2 col3 info
num1 data1 Y info1
num2 data2 N info2
num3 data3 NULL NULL
```

Also, if my T2 is not a table, is a excel file instead, is it possible to write a script to import the data to T1 and update T1 at the same time?

Comment: Is col3 already a field in T1?

Comment: Nope, it is a new colum.

Comment: So, are you also looking for the code (ALTER TABLE) to add the new column?

Comment: Yes. But it will cause too much touble i could manually add the new column and do update. I am more concern the script for update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to add `col3` manually to `T1`.  The update script is a two-parter: an Update and an Insert

```
UPDATE T1
SET
  T1.col3 = T2.col3  
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.col1 = T2.col1;

INSERT INTO T1
  (col1, col2, col3, info)
  SELECT T2.col1, T2.col2, T2.col3, NULL 
  FROM T2
  WHERE NOT T2.col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM T1);
```

In order for `T2` to be an Excel file, you would need to set `T2` up as an OLEDB table (using a Linked Server and a MS Jet driver).